# What is the explicit python3 type for dict_keys for isinstance() check?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, key, typechecking

In Python3, what type should I use to check if the dictionary keys belong to it?

```
>>> d = {1 : 2}
>>> type(d.keys())
<class 'dict_keys'>
```

So naturally I tried this:

```
>>> isinstance(d.keys(), dict_keys)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'dict_keys' is not defined
```

What should I put in place of the explicit `dict_keys` as 2nd argument for `isinstance`?

(This is useful as I have to handle unknown input variables that can take the form of dictionary keys. And I know using `list(d.keys())` can convert to a list (recovering Python2 behavior) but that's not an option in this case.)

Comment: Do you want to check if a value or variable exists in dictionary keys? Try this: ```>>> d = {1:2}
>>> if 1 in d:print("1 is a key")```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use [`collections.abc.KeysView`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.KeysView):

```
In [19]: isinstance(d.keys(), collections.abc.KeysView)
Out[19]: True
```

> `collections.abc` module provides abstract base classes that can be
>   used to test whether a class provides a particular interface

Comment: In python 3.6.3 I am able to `instanceof(d.keys(), collections.KeysView)` (no abc)

Comment: @MarkNS DeprecationWarning: Using or importing the ABCs from 'collections' instead of from 'collections.abc' is deprecated, and in 3.8 it will stop working

Comment: For anyone checking this out later, FWIW the 3.8 date was pushed back and it seems that `from collections import x` will work until python 3.10 (with a warning of course and would be ill advises on new code, use `collections.abc` instead.

Answer (score 13):

Using built-in type():

```
isinstance(d.keys(), type({}.keys()))
```